# Django-import-export get file name

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I've been scouring the docs and internet for a couple days now trying to figure out how I can capture the imported filename from Django import export admin panel's import feature.

Basically, I want to save this filename to ensure that future file uploads are not the same.

the process being:

1. Someone imports a file

[image: picture of admin panel with import button]

2. The filename is stored

[image: admin panel, import file section]

3. If someone tries to upload same file again, error

[image: error in file import]

But I can't figure out how to get that filename from Django import export. Help is much appreciated.

Update 2/15/2018: I'm creating a work-around in the views.py using tablib and intercepting the data before Django-import-export takes over. Spirits are high.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the file name in [many pre/post function parameters](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.after_import_instance), my example updating the file name of the records:

```
class MyResouce(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = MyDjangoModel

    def after_import_instance(self, instance, new, **kwargs):
        # update file name
        file_name = kwargs.get('file_name', 'unknown')
        instance.source = file_name
```